# Gulp exclusion glob syntax

Tags: node.js, glob, gulp

I am facing a problem under gulp for a simple task.
I don't find a way to exclude all files from a folder excluding that ones which are in a specific child folder.

Here is how my files are organized :

```
public/
____app/
________file4.txt
________js/
____________admin/
________________files1.txt
________________files2.txt
____________otherfolder/
________________files3.txt
____________file4.txt
```

I am trying to get all files included in app (only file4.txt in my example) and in the app/js/admin folder (no the one in js that are not in admin).

Here is my glob syntax :

`['public/app/js/admin/**/*.txt', '!public/app/js/**', 'public/app/**']`

With this command, it only return file4.txt and an empty js folder.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is somewhat of an ongoing issue.  https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/issues/25

I used Aaron Bushnell's example which in this case would be.

```
['public/app/js/admin/**/*.txt', '!public/app/{js,js/**}', 'public/app/**']
```